# Can't get around compile error about fixed sized buffers in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, typedef, unsafe

I'm trying to create some structures in C# to mimic ones from some C++ Microsoft header files.  My code is as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe public struct _NotifyData
{
    fixed uint adwData[2];
    public struct Data
    {
        uint cbBuf;
        IntPtr pBuff;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA
{
    public ushort Type;
    public ushort Field;
    public uint Reserved;
    public uint Id;
    public _NotifyData NotifyData;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe public struct PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO
{
    public uint Version;
    public uint Flags;
    public uint Count;
    fixed PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA aData[1];  //Compiler complains here!!!
}
```

The compiler complains about my `aData[1]` variable in my declaration of `struct PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO`.  I've encountered a handfull of these and adding `fixed` to the variable in question and `unsafe` to the structure declaration seemed to work.  Except for this structure that is.  The error I get is this:

> Fixed size buffer type must be one of the following: bool, byte, short, int, long, char, sbyte, ushort, uint, ulong, float or double

Now I can see that the type I'm using is not one of the listed types, but according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f5zx2bz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), putting `unsafe` in front of the struct declaration should allow me to use types other than the ones listed.  For some reason it is not letting me.

Comment: The page you link doesn't say anything about using `unsafe` to get rid of error. On the contrary, they give an example that would cause the error, and it uses `unsafe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't declare fixed-size array of custom `struct`s in C#, as the error message and the page you linked to (I suggest you reread it) say.

**EDIT**: Removed incorrect info. See David Heffernan's answer for a way to solve this.

Comment: @Ultratrunks I don't understand why you accepted this answer. What will you do when `Count>1`? Removing compiler errors is not enough, you also need the code to do the right thing at runtime.

Comment: Then the documentation is really confusing, because it is declared as an array of length 1.

Comment: I did re-read that Microsoft link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f5zx2bz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.  And right above the example it says "The following sample generates CS1663."  And then gives a chunk of code where they try create an unsafe structure with a fixed array of type 'string'.  The example was giving an example of something that DOES NOT work.  Little confused there is all, thanks.

Comment: @svick That's just how variable length arrays are declared in C structs.

Comment: @David:  I mis-quoted the Microsoft link.  It explicitly is telling me I can NOT make fixed arrays of any type I choose.  It must be in the provided list of types.

Comment: @Ultra Documentation of compiler errors always gives code examples that produce those compiler errors!

Comment: @Ultra I still don't understand why you accepted this answer though. You can't get hold of the `PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA` this way.

Comment: @svick I've upvoted you for your edit. I'm honestly not trying to steal your thunder or anything but I think it's important that accepted answers on SO, especially on topics like this are accurate.

Answer (score 4):

I have a couple of suggestions.

First of all `_NotifyData` is a union and should look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct _NotifyData
{
    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=2)]
    public uint[] adwData;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public struct Data
    {
        uint cbBuf;
        IntPtr pBuff;
    }
}
```

Secondly, `PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO` simply can't be handled by the P/invoke marshaller. You will have to use manual marshalling, i.e. [`Marshal.PtrToStructure()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) to get anywhere. The documentation for the `ppPrinterNotifyInfo` parameter of [`FindNextPrinterChangeNotification()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162723%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> A pointer to a pointer variable that receives a pointer to a system-allocated, read-only buffer. Call the FreePrinterNotifyInfo function to free the buffer when you are finished with it. This parameter can be NULL if no information is required.

You should pass an `IntPtr` as an `out` parameter and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to read out the contents into your own data structures. Something like this:

```
IntPtr PrinterNotifyInfo;
FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(..., out PrinterNotifyInfo);
IntPtr pCount = PrinterNotifyInfo + 2*Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint));
uint Count = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(pCount);
IntPtr pData = pCount + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint));
for (int i=0; i<Count; i++)
{
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA Data = (PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pData, typeof(PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA));
    pData += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA));
}
```

I've not attempted to compile this but hopefully it gets the idea across.

Comment: I'm working in legacy code for a product I didn't develop, and later in the code this exact marshaling that you show here is going on.  I was just trying to go against the grain, and in my mind more correctly defining the structures. I should have just left it alone though.

Comment: Variable length C arrays in structs have to be marshalled the way I demonstrate here. The only potential candidate is `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` but that doesn't work because it has to be used with `SizeConst` and you don't know that at compile time.